# jQuery Change Background images while scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, image, background, scroll

I've been struggling with trying to make my  background image change while scrolling.  I tried the solutions posted to similar questions but so far no luck, it will only display the first background image.

Basically I have the background set to a fixed position and several divs, each the size of the viewport and each with a top margin the size of the viewport's height. In other words, when scrolling, the user only sees the  background image after they scroll past each div.  I want the background image to change after they've scrolled past each div.

Here's the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowY = $(window).height();
    var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
    var image_url = '/images/image1.jpg';

    if (scrolledY > windowY) {
        image_url = '/images/image2.jpg';
        }

    $('body').css('background', "url(" + img_url + ")");

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is malformed, check the value for 'background', it has an errant paren and is not closed properly.

Comment: Put the background change inside your scroll function, or give it a separate function name that you call in the if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two typos, the parentheses then your `image_url` variable name. Initially you had:

```
$(body).css('background', "url(" + img_url) + "'";
```

Change to:

```
$(body).css('background', "url(" + image_url + ")");
```

The parentheses were incorrect and ultimately so was your final, concatenated string. Also, your variable was declared as `image_url`, but in your `css` function you used `img_url`.

Comment: Oops, good catch, thanks!  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference, the corrected code still isn't working :/

Comment: Are you able to set a `debugger` or `alert`s in your function to check whether or not your `scrolledY` value is behaving as expected? Just trying to narrow down to possibilities!

Comment: Yep, the scrolledY seems to be fine, setting an alert right after the img_url inside the if statement displays the pixels scrolled as soon as I pass 640px. However no alert shows if I set it after the $(body).css statement, so for some reason that's where the problem must be!

Comment: Have you checked errors? Because before you had syntax errors there, you say you fixed it though. Are you able to repost the exact code you're using now? Just to make sure?

Comment: Oh! There was another typo with your `css` function call, I updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome, that seems to have done the trick!  I'm always amazed at how many stupid typos manage to slip past me... Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! Also, typos are the bane of our existence as developers! :D

Answer (score 0):

Change the call to your background property

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowY = $(window).height();
    var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
    var image_url = '/images/image1.jpg';

    if (scrolledY > windowY) {
    image_url = '/images/image2.jpg';
    backgroundChange(image_url);
    }
});


function backgroundChange(img_url){
  $("body").css("background", "url(" + img_url + ")");
}
```

Comment: unfortunately no luck with that either

Comment: Ok, it is still a good idea to place it seperately so you can call it with whatever image.
Did you try placing the function outside the $(document).ready(....) ..? Of course always check the paths. Often it is just simply that. Upon second look towards your code it should work. Check firebug console!